# Tooltip cutoff at the edge of the containing element

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="word-container" >
    <span tooltip-def="To sign or give formal approval to.">
      <span class="define-word highlight-word">ratifying</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.word-container [tooltip-def] {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.word-container [tooltip-def]:before {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-color: #323232 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px 6px 0 6px;
  content: "";
  display: none;
  top: -6px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.word-container [tooltip-def]:after {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  content: attr(tooltip-def);
  background: #323232;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  font-family: open sans;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -6px;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-100%);
  width: auto;
  z-index: 99;
}
.word-container [tooltip-def]:hover:after,
.word-container [tooltip-def]:hover:before {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The tooltip is cut off on the left side. I tried `overflow: visible` and higher z-index on `.word-container [tooltip-def]:after`, but none of the working.

Here is the jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mddc/5dtwr6zc/10/

How can I make minimal CSS changes to make the tooltip visible? Move to the right side when the left side touches the browser edge?

Comment: I may be missing the point here, but it seems to me that the tooltip is just falling outside of the viewport. If you were to place more text in front of the span that triggers the tooltip, you should see the entire thing. @curious1

Comment: Move the tooltip to the right side in this case?

Comment: You can not have it done using just CSS, if i really understood what you want. You would need something *(js/jQuery)* that would be able to get the current position of element, based on which the tooltip will be positioned dynamically. *(Just like Mac or Windows Right Click Context Menu)*

Answer (score 0):

you are going great you only need to change the css. below is the css code apply and check.

```
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.word-container [tooltip-def] {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.word-container [tooltip-def]:before {
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-color: #323232 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px 6px 0 6px;
  content: "";
  display: none;
  top: -6px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.word-container [tooltip-def]:after {
  left: 20%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  content: attr(tooltip-def);
  background: #323232;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  font-family: open sans;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -6px;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-100%);
  width: auto;
  z-index: 99;
}
.word-container [tooltip-def]:hover:after,
.word-container [tooltip-def]:hover:before {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me! This solution moves the tooltip to the right even when a word is not at the left edge.

Answer (score 0):

I've made the changes which can be viewed in the fiddle below

https://jsfiddle.net/5dtwr6zc/14/

```
.test{
 overflow: visible;
}
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.word-container [tooltip-def] {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.word-container [tooltip-def]:before {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-color: #323232 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px 6px 0 6px;
  content: "";
  display: none;
  top: -6px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.word-container [tooltip-def]:after {
  left: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-47%);
  content: attr(tooltip-def);
  background: #323232;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  font-family: open sans;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -6px;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-100%);
  width: auto;
  z-index: 99;
}
.word-container [tooltip-def]:hover:after,
.word-container [tooltip-def]:hover:before {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The problem was the positioning of the after psuedo element. But I would strongly suggest to make the positioning dynamic as per the context using JavaScript

Comment: Hi John, this moves the tooltip text to the right even when a word is not at the left edge. Thanks for helping me!